# read and display the content of txt file from database in index page

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, php-5.3

In php how to make the index page read from a text file saved in TXT folder  and the text name is already saved in mysqli databse, am new to php and database.
here is the database table

[image]

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: php mysql select data from db  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: This is not a "code that for me". Google it yourself and ask if you get stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the text file name from SQL, then use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the text file contents.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$connection= new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT name FROM new_record");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $fileName = $row['name'];
        $fileContents = file_get_contents("/TXT/$fileName");
        echo $fileContents;
    }
```

Comment: hes asking for getting from database

Comment: He's asking how to make the index page read from text file saved into TXT folder, when the text file name is in SQL database.

Comment: and how to get text file name from db?